# How to import huge time series data from (DRF) to user interface (UI)

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, bigdata, redistimeseries

How to import huge time series data from (DRF) to user interface (UI)

**Hello**, I am fetching data from Redis TimeSeries using the mrange command, and it returns data of around 4-5MB in size. I need to transfer this large data to the UI, but I don't know how to handle such a large dataset. I tried splitting it into smaller chunks, but in React, when the data arrives in chunks, it triggers a re-render for each data point, resulting in too many renders per second, which is not desirable. **How can I transfer such a large dataset efficiently**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.